# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms error in selenium web driver

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium 2.47.1 version.But today , I got below errors when I ran one of my sample script

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:276)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:223)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:212)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
at eNotes.ENotes.SetBaseUrl(ENotes.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:641)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:609)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
```

What is went wrong actually..? Please help me on this...

Comment: I am working on Linux

Comment: I am running Test Scripts using Jenkins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should install a x server.
    apt-get install xvfb

set PATH => export DISPLAY=:40 
 
after installation, run it:
    sudo nohup Xvfb :40 -ac &  => 40 is display number

to make setup for jenkins, you can use Xvfb plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin

Comment: `Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055` getting this exception

Comment: @Karthik did you fix it?

Comment: HI, I have installed Jenkins on Client's Server machine. I am waiting for their command to install Xvfb on server.

Comment: Hi not that commands i'm talking about.. That server does not have X or X-windows running. Its a headless server. If there is anyway to fix this..?

Comment: Hi, Client is thinking that installation of xvfb on the server may create some issues in server..?

Comment: what issues can be? so, run your test on Windows server.

Comment: how did you fix problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on linux.
Run:

```
xhost +
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".